# Relation between hooks and service's units in juju

Tags: juju, maas

Is the relation between hooks and services's units one-to-one or one-to-many?

Consider:

1. I have one charm as a service in juju.
2. If I add another unit to same service, the system creates another hook for that new unit? Or new unit uses same hook?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can think of hooks as 'hook scripts'. Whenever an action happens which corresponds to an available hook script it gets executed.

Example: When you add another unit to one of two related services the appropriate relation hooks get called to set up this new unit.